# Why is my mongo query using the $in operator producting an error?

Tags: mongodb

The following query is erroring out:

```
const pastOrders = await Order.find(
        {user: userId},
        {status: {$in: ["delivered", "refunded"]}}
    ).populate({
        path: 'items.product',
        model: 'Product'
    });
```

The error:

```
 MongoServerError: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: string
```

The schema of status is as follows:

```
status: {
  type: String,
  default: 'pending',      
  required: true
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
.find({user: userId, status: {$in: ["delivered", "refunded"]}})
```

No need to for the `},{` after `userId`